# Power BI - Conditional Formatting in a Table Visual that has only one value

Tags: powerbi

I'm creating a report in Power BI that shows performance for many measurements across a few different levels of granularity.

The performance is being aggregated into a 100% Stacked Bar Chart visual that displays the percentage of measurements in each of the three buckets "Above, Below, or At Target"
[Aggregation Buckets Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1dJM.png)

From there, I need to apply an additional level of logic that has some hard-coded thresholds to determine if the bar is "Great, Good, Okay, or Bad". For example: "If you have less that 20% below target (red), and 50% above target (green), you're doing great!" Then I have to put that text in a tool tip so that it pops up when they hover over the bar visual.

This is all working fine, and until the "Percentage of measures Below Target" DAX measure everything is being done on the SQL side.

The issue is at the tool tip step. They don't just want the "great!" value, they want the background for Great/Good/Okay/Bad to show as Blue/Green/White/Red.

I figured this would be easily done with a table visual and conditional formatting based on the value of a measure, but there's a quirk with how these three things interact when the table only has a one row of data. When there's only one row with only a measure, the table considers it aggregated, which 
 [prevents the conditional formatting from taking effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eopjn.png) However, when there are multiple rows, [or a non-measure value is added and de-aggregated](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Conditional-Formatting-not-working-for-one-row-table/td-p/642126), the conditional formatting [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kn9s.png) (this is a picture of the whole table, the extra column only has one value) The issue here is that the meaningless column is bad for presentation.

I'm learning Power BI/DAX as I go, so any help understanding the issue or how I can work around it would be appreciated.